# In MySQL, What's the best way track timestamp for changes (adding columns)in a table?

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp

I have a table in my database that will add a column and insert some values in that column periodically. I know TIMESTAMP function can track update changes, but that works for only one column in a table. However I'm wondering what is the best way if I want a full record of when these columns in that table were added? Say, I added 50 columns during 30 days, sequentially. Ideally, I would like to have another table which records some time-stamps telling me when each of the columns was added. Alternatively, I'm wondering if it's possible to make each column have a property which allows you know check when this column was added?

**************** As a specific example**************
For example, I've 20K customers with their purchases within 6 months be my interest. On the first day, I created the following table:

[CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS

USERID INT(6) NOT NULL, COL1 VARCHAR(256)

PRIMARY KEY(USERID)]

Then I will keep checking their purchased items for 6 months. The problem is I don't observed when they made a purchase, only that whether a purchase has been made by the time when I check their order records. So knowing that a new purchased was made after last time I checked and before current check is essential, i.e., I need to know the dates and times for my every check behavior.

Then after I created the table, I will go check the customers' purchased records periodically and add a column to my table for current check results, inserting values that list purchased items for each customer. Then after 6 months, I will have, maybe 200 columns added for the 200 check behaviors. How could I know when each of columns was added?

Many thanks!

Comment: If you are adding *50 columns during 30 days* there is a design problem. You should not add columns, but think of a separate table where you add records to store the info you now store in columns.

Comment: Thank you trincot. I'm talking about columns. The 50 columns in 30 days was just for example. By design problem, did you mean this would make interaction with database too frequent? I've also thought about creating a table for each customer, then I could insert values in row every time I check this customer's purchases. And then I'll have a TIMESTAMP column in each customer's table that tells me when each row value was inserted. But my concern about doing so is that, I will have 20K unique tables for the 20K customers, not sure whether this will cause some problems...

Comment: I was just updating my comment. Yes, you should not use a table like that. Create a new table that references the primary key of the main table and has columns with timestamp, total purchase, and whatever else you want to log at that time.

Comment: Give some example data (few of those columns also) in your question, and then we can make the similar thing with a better design (and your timestamp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your purposes you should not be adding a column to your table on a regular basis. Instead you should be adding records to another table.

You could name that table for instance `customer_reports` and define the following columns for it:

```
user_id  -- reference to customers table
report_date -- the date you added this record
report_text -- whatever you want to note down for this customer and time
```

So if you want to enter some text for customer 254, you would not add a column to the `customers` table, but add a row to this new table:

```
insert into `customer_reports`
values (254, curdate, 'This customer has been very active the last 6 months');
```

And to select the whole history of reports for that customer you would:

```
select    c.fullname, cr.*
from      customers c
left join customer_reports cr
       on cr.userid = c.userid
where     c.userid = 254
order by  cr.report_date;
```

In general you should be alarmed when you find yourself creating a table with many columns that represent the same type of information. This is hardly ever a good design. Read about [normalisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: Thank you trincot for the suggestion. So if I understand correctly what I could do is to inset a row record for each customer at each time I check his data. If I have 20K customers and I checked their data for 50 times then this table will keeping growing and will end up having 20K*50=1,000,000 rows. This will make things much more easier than adding columns or having too many tables. However, will having many rows (millions of rows) cause a database performance problem? Thank u!

Comment: It should not lead to performance problems. It would be good to have an index created on the combination (userid, report_date) to improve lookup speed. I find it amazing that you would be able to type millions of meaningful entries in a few years. If however, many of those entries are copy/paste, then also that you need to rethink.